# Capacitance to useful signal conversion

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, capacitance

Working on a project, where we need to measure the change in capacitance(capacitance change roughly from 0.5 pF at the start, to 20 pF at the end of the measurement). On the variable cap, only the distance between the plates of the capacitor is changing. I was thinking about RF oscillator, but have no idea, how to convert the frequency to voltage. And if this is even suited for such an application and it must have at least 10 measurements per second. I'm a newbie in this field so it would be great if someone could explain to me the circuit diagram for this application.

Comment: You can generate a variable PWM signal using something like 555 timer, if it is more "useful" to you rather than frequency.

Comment: How are you going to capture the data for measurement?

Answer (score 0):

Frequency is usually easier to measure than voltage, so you might see better stability and performance measuring frequency with a frequency counter than with an analog input voltage.

The 555 timer uses an RC circuit to create oscillations with a frequency that depends on the resistance and capacitance.
https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2011/oct/humidity-sensors-and-signal-conditioning-choices
Shows how one can be used to oscillate at a rate proportional to a variable capacitor, but the reason we'd recommend a 555 is it's very well documented for all skill levels.

When you have a better idea of what you want to do with a frequency measurement go ahead and ask about it and I'm sure someone can help you out.